# Difference between ～というのは～ and ～のは～

Tags: grammar

For instance, from [here](http://maggiesensei.com/2010/04/24/request-lesson-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86toiu-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%EF%BC%88toiukoto-and-many-more/):

> あれだけ勉強｛べんきょう｝したのに試験｛しけん｝に失敗｛しっぱい｝したというのは信｛しん｝じられない。

with the meaning of

> I can’t believe (the fact) that I failed the exam after studying so much.

Is there a difference between that and this?

> あれだけ勉強｛べんきょう｝したのに試験｛しけん｝に失敗｛しっぱい｝したのは信｛しん｝じられない。

My understanding is that it remains gramatical since the の acts as a noun, and the verb clause before that modifies the の. Would it be fine to view them both as interchangable?

Comment: Related: [のは Vs. というのは　What is the Difference?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56332/5010)

Comment: @naruto Thanks.