# Meaning of っていうのは without っていうことだ

Tags: grammar, meaning

> あんた、だって、懐かしいっていうのは昔行った場所に久しぶりに行くから感じるんやろ

Came across this sentence while playing a visual novel and just had a small question.

Would I be correct in saying there is a ということ omitted just after the 感じる? I just can't really wrap my head around the っていうのは and the sentence ending with a verb in 感じるんやろ. Is the ん in 感じるんやろ the same ん as in んだ, or is it the same as in say 赤いのはこれだ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think nothing is omitted after 感じる. 感じるということんやろ is ungrammatical in the first place. But ん in 感じるんやろ is explanatory-no, the same ん in んだ/のだ.

Starting from this:

> 昔行った場所に久しぶりに行くから、懐かしいと感じる。
> Because you go somewhere long after the last visit, you feel nostalgic.

Changing the word order for emphasis ([cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010)):

> 懐かしいっていう**のは**昔行った場所に久しぶりに行くから感じる。
> It's because you go somewhere long after the last visit that you feel nostalgic.
> → "Nostalgic" is something you feel because you go somewhere long after the first visit.

<sup>(Here っていうのは is basically an [emphatic version of のは](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56332/5010), but it's mandatory because bare 懐かしい cannot work as a subject.)</sup>

Adding だって and んやろ (which is dialectal のだろう, explanatory-の + だろう):

> **だって**、懐かしいっていうのは昔行った場所に久しぶりに行くから感じる**んやろ**。
> But..."nostalgic" is something you feel because you go somewhere long after the last visit, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any other examples of cleft sentences like that? I still have a little trouble wrapping my head around it

Comment: why can it not work as a subject? Is it because 懐かしい is inherently subjective?

Comment: @leemoran Please search with ["cleft sentence" on this site](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22cleft%20sentence%22).

Comment: @Fireheart251 Because a subject must be a noun, not a bare i-adjective or a verb. (In short catchphrase-like sentences it may be sometimes permitted; see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62983/5010))